# Possible undefined value returns when in function callback

Tags: typescript

If I have a variable that's undefined, I can do an if guard check for typescript to recognize that it is not undefined.

```
let x: { value: number; } | undefined = { value: 23 };

if(!x) {
    process.exit(1);
}
```

And now `x` can not be undefined. But if I use the variable in a callback, the possibility of it being undefined comes back:

```
let x: { value: number; } | undefined = { value: 23 };

if(!x) {
    process.exit(1);
}

() => {
     x.value;
     // error: x could possibly be undefined
};
```

I understand why they decided to do this, as other code can be called before the callback is called that alters the value of x, making it undefined again.

How do I assert that x will not change afterwards, or retype it?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK, the next best thing would be to make `x` non-nullable and then remember to check if it really is at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use `const` for the variable instead of `let` - a `const` can't be reassigned, and from that, TypeScript can understand that if the variable is `undefined` after one test, it'll always be `undefined`.

If you use `let`, it's possible to reassign it to `undefined` before the callback runs, which is why TypeScript warns against it - for example:

```
// runs first
action(() => {
    x = undefined;
});
// runs second
action(() => {
     x.value;
     // x is DEFINITELY undefined
});
```

Comment: Typescript does know `process.exit` will result in no further code running. It properly removes the possibility of it being undefined *until* the variable is used in a callback.

Comment: I can't use `const` as i do have some code in between that sets the value of x (x is initially undefined). After the if check though it doesn't change. I could use `const` if I abstract the value of x to a function, which probably is a better idea. I am aware why typescript does this, was checking if there was a hacky way.

Comment: No good way. TypeScript in general works a lot better when you use `const` for everything, and can define everything in one go when the variable gets declared.